# Updating WinDbg Preview

Tags: windbg

I have installed WinDbg Preview from Microsoft Store and I use it a lot, because the usability is so much better than the old versions.

I now became aware that there's a new version of WinDbg: 1.2308.2002.0. However, the Microsoft store says that I already have the latest version - which is 1.2306.14001.0

How can I update WinDbg Preview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WinDbg Preview is no longer WinDbg Preview. It's now WinDbg officially. The preview will not receive updates through the Microsoft Store any longer.

Instead, you get the official version through [aka.ms/windbg](https://aka.ms/windbg) and it will have the new UI.

The old official versions are now called "WinDbg classic".

Comment: I get "This app package is not supported for installation by App Installer because it uses certain restricted capabilities.". Looks like it uses the same Windows Store technology that disables it in many corporate environments.

Comment: @mark: Okay. Sorry. I can't tell you much about that.

Comment: Here is what I did - downloaded the app installer. This is a text file mentioning https://windbg.download.prss.microsoft.com/dbazure/prod/1-2308-2002-0/windbg.msixbundle. I downloaded the msixbundle, still cannot run it, but I could extract 3 msix files from it. They still cannot be run, but their content can be extracted. Seems like a plain copy installation - just extract to a directory and run DbgX.Shell.exe executable.

Comment: added an answer with a batch script that did  the same

Comment: I also get the same message, unable to install on 21 Nov 2023.

"This app package is not supported for installation by App Installer because it uses certain restricted capabilities."

Answer (score 3):

well this is a batch script that i used to run a latest windbg
when the appinstaller / powershell spat out access denied errors and
uninstallable errors

```
wget --quiet --continue  --no-check-certificate -O windbg.appinstaller https://aka.ms/windbg/download
grep -ioP "htt.*bundle" windbg.appinstaller > msix.txt
wget --quiet --continue  --no-check-certificate -i msix.txt
7z.exe x windbg.msixbundle 
7z.exe x *x64.msix -owindbgnew
cd windbgnew
start dbgx.shell.exe
```

Answer (score 1):

After updating the Windows `AppInstaller` from the MS app store, the install works on `21 Nov 2023.`