# What does "64-bit machine not using 64-bit API" output by windbg mean?

Tags: windbg

I have a Linux .Net Core memory dump which I open in WinDbg. And it displays the following message - **64-bit machine not using 64-bit API**

I use Windows 11 and I have just installed WinDbg from the latest Windows SDK:

```
0:000> version
Generic Unix Version 0 UP Free x64
Machine Name:
System Uptime: not available
Process Uptime: not available
Target Composition Target

Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 10.0.22621.1778 AMD64
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

command line: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\windbg.exe" '  Debugger Process 0x6E34 
dbgeng:  image 10.0.22621.1778, 
        [path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\dbgeng.dll]
dbghelp: image 10.0.22621.1778, 
        [path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\dbghelp.dll]
        DIA version: 30795
Extension DLL search Path:
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\WINXP;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\winext;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\winext\arcade;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\pri;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64;C:\Users\p11f70f\AppData\Local\Dbg\EngineExtensions;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64;C:\Program Files\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\wbin;C:\Program Files\Python39\;C:\Program Files\Python39\Scripts\;C:\ProgramData\Boxstarter;C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-17.0.1.12-hotspot\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Plantronics\Spokes3G\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn\;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Users\p11f70f\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;c:\dayforce\utils;C:\Users\p11f70f\.dotnet\tools;C:\Users\p11f70f\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\p11f70f\AppData\Local\Programs\Fiddler;C:\Users\p11f70f\.dotnet\tools;C:\Users\p11f70f\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\p11f70f\AppData\Local\Programs\Azure Data Studio\bin;~\.terraform;C:\Users\p11f70f\AppData\Roaming\nvm;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\;C:\Users\p11f70f\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;c:\dayforce\utils;C:\Users\p11f70f\.dotnet\tools;C:\Users\p11f70f\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\p11f70f\AppData\Local\Programs\Fiddler;C:\Users\p11f70f\.dotnet\tools;C:\Users\p11f70f\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\p11f70f\AppData\Local\Programs\Azure Data Studio\bin;C:\Users\p11f70f\.terraform;c:\utils;C:\Users\p11f70f\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin;C:\Users\p11f70f\AppData\Roaming\nvm;C:\Program Files\nodejs;c:\utils\bind\;
Extension DLL chain:
    ELFBinComposition: image 10.0.22621.1778, API 0.0.0, 
        [path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\winext\ELFBinComposition.dll]
    dbghelp: image 10.0.22621.1778, API 10.0.6, 
        [path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\dbghelp.dll]
    uext: image 10.0.22621.1778, API 1.0.0, 
        [path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\winext\uext.dll]
```

The WinDbg process was started from **C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64**

**EDIT 1**

The line is output at the very beginning upon loading a crash dump:

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 10.0.22621.1778 AMD64
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


Loading Dump File [C:\Temp\dumps\clean_coredump]
64-bit machine not using 64-bit API

...
```

I tried to open the same core dump in the WinDbg Preview app, but it fails completely:

```
icrosoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 10.0.22549.1000 AMD64
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


Loading Dump File [C:\Temp\dumps\clean_coredump]
Could not match Dump File signature - invalid file format
Could not open dump file [C:\Temp\dumps\clean_coredump], Win32 error 0n87
    "The parameter is incorrect."
```

Granted, the WinDbg Preview is not the newest, but I do not know how to update it - the Windows Store is blocked on my machine.

**EDIT 2**

I was able to install the modern WinDBG by following these steps:

1. Download the appinstaller from https://aka.ms/windbg. I cannot run it (seems like a Windows Store tech, which is blocked here). But it is a text file mentioning https://windbg.download.prss.microsoft.com/dbazure/prod/1-2308-2002-0/windbg.msixbundle
2. Download windbg.msixbundle, still not runnable, but it is an archive, so I extracted the file windbg_win7-x86.msix, windbg_win7-x64.msix and windbg_win-arm64.msix
3. Still cannot run the msix file, but they in turn can be extracted to separate folders. Inside there is an executable DbgX.Shell.exe which seems to be the debugger.

However, even using this version, I still get the same message. Here is the complete output after the dump is loaded:

```
************* Preparing the environment for Debugger Extensions Gallery repositories **************
   ExtensionRepository : Implicit
   UseExperimentalFeatureForNugetShare : true
   AllowNugetExeUpdate : true
   AllowNugetMSCredentialProviderInstall : true
   AllowParallelInitializationOfLocalRepositories : true

   -- Configuring repositories
      ----> Repository : LocalInstalled, Enabled: true
      ----> Repository : UserExtensions, Enabled: true

>>>>>>>>>>>>> Preparing the environment for Debugger Extensions Gallery repositories completed, duration 0.000 seconds

************* Waiting for Debugger Extensions Gallery to Initialize **************

>>>>>>>>>>>>> Waiting for Debugger Extensions Gallery to Initialize completed, duration 0.032 seconds
   ----> Repository : UserExtensions, Enabled: true, Packages count: 0
   ----> Repository : LocalInstalled, Enabled: true, Packages count: 36

Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 10.0.25921.1001 AMD64
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


Loading Dump File [C:\Temp\dumps\clean_coredump]
64-bit machine not using 64-bit API

************* Path validation summary **************
Response                         Time (ms)     Location
Deferred                                       srv*...*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
Symbol search path is: srv*...*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
Executable search path is: 
Generic Unix Version 0 UP Free x64
System Uptime: not available
Process Uptime: not available
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
..........................................
*** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for libpthread-2.31.so
*** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for libcoreclr.so
libpthread_2_31!pthread_cond_wait+0x1e2:
00007454`1e1637b2 483d00f0ffff    cmp     rax,0FFFFFFFFFFFFF000h
```

Comment: Which command produces that output? It's not part of the `version` output. Have you tried WinDbg 1.x instead of WinDbg classic 10.x? https://stackoverflow.com/a/77021531/480982

Comment: Please, see **EDIT 1**.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info. Would you mind sharing the crash dump with me? I don't have a Linux crash dump to work with. 
The windows store version is no longer maintained anyway. See the linked question to download the official new WinDbg 1.x version. It uses debugging engine 10.0.25921.1001

Comment: @ThomasWeller - I would really love to, but I am afraid my dev manager would not authorize it. Is interactive session an option?

Comment: Cannot install - commented on the linked SO answer.